# How to use .svg in XSLT2.0?

Tags: xslt-2.0, apache-fop

I am seeing similar to .ttf files; there are files with .svg extension as well

Can we use those .svg files similarly like .ttf files ? Or is there any other use case for which we can use these .svg(s) ?

I am using fop-2.8

Comment: SVG is an XML format so you can process it with XSLT, like any XML. In the context of FOP it is possible to use an SVG image, see https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/trunk/graphics.html#svg "FOP uses Apache Batik for SVG support. This format can be handled as an `fo:instream-foreign-object` or in a separate file referenced with `fo:external-graphic`".